# Initialize 2D arrayList with specified number of columns but not rows?

Tags: java, arraylist

I want to make a 2D ArrayList, with the number of columns already specified but not the rows.
For example, I want to create a table with 26 columns and 0 or 1 columns at first, then after each loop of doing something else, the number of rows will increase along with that loop.

When I increase the number of rows (length of an ArrayList of ArrayLists), I also want all 26 arrays to increase as well. What is the syntax for it?

And how would I index into, or add a new item into a specific location - say `array[2][3] = item`?

BTW this is a DFSA table converted from a NFSA table

Comment: It won't exactly be a two-dimensional list; it'll be a list of lists.  What do you intend to do with this structure?  The syntax isn't difficult, but I'm curious if you're looking for a solution that could be expressed more elegantly.

Comment: you should consider creating a class to hold the 26 columns and just use a list containing instances of that class. lists of lists are difficult to maintain because of readability issues.

Comment: @Makoto im writing a String data structure that is represented like a table with fixed # of columns and the # of rows will be incremented, I need to access all of the 1st row in order to add another length for the rows on the table. This is the DFSA table converted from the NFSA one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could have a list of lists, essentially something like so:

```
List<List<String>> table = new ArrayList<List<String>>();
```

Then add the 26 columns:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 26; i++)
{
    table.add(new ArrayList<String>());
}
```

You can then have a method, called, say, `addToColumn(int column, String value, List<List<String>> table)` in which you do something like so:

```
for(int i = 0; i < table.size(); i++)
{
    if(i == column)
    {
        table.get(i).add(value);
    }
    else
    {
        table.get(i).add("");
    }
}
```

This should allow you to have lists which grow together. Of course, my assumption in the above is that you will be entering one element at a time.

Alternatively, you can do something like so:

```
public void addToColumns(Map<int, String> data, List<List<String>> table)
{
    for(int key : data.keyset())
    {
        table.get(key).add(data.get(key));
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < table.size(); i++)
    {
        if(!data.containsKey(i))
        {
            table.get(i).add("");
        }
    }
}
```

The above algorithm should allow you to add items to multiple columns, while filling the rest up with empty strings. This should allow you to end up with rows of equal length. Also, the map will be used to store a key-value pair where the key is the column number, and the value will be whatever string you would like to throw in there. This will allow you to populate your table one row at a time.

Comment: @Herious: The `List` interface exposes a `get(int index)` method, so assuming that you have already populated your list, you can do a `table.get(0).get(1)`. Note however that since your lists will be populated incrementally, trying to access that location **before** you have actually populated anything will cause an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

Comment: @Herious: Are you sure you have created a list of lists of strings rather than a list of strings?

Answer (score -1):

You can simply create an array by giving only the number of rows:

```
int[][] array = new int[4][];
```

Now you may treat your array as the transpose of what you have defined so if you want to enter an element at 3rd column of 2nd row you can enter as transpose i.e.

```
array[3][2]=5;
```

Comment: I think you're reading the question a little *too* fast, here.

Comment: Considering the question asks about ArrayLists, and you're answering with arrays...I'll stand by what I've said.

Comment: @Makoto: Please look at the example he has given : And how would I index into, or add a new item into a specific location - say array[2][3] = item?

Comment: That's a for-instance.  That's how they would reference elements if it were a standard two-dimensional array, but they're attempting to do that *with an ArrayList*.